# Firefox scripting language: URL of active Tab and counting open Tabs

Tags: firefox-addon

Edit: I was able to go one step further :)

PSEUDO CODE (what I want)

```
if (CurrentTabURL == empty Tab) and (Tab.Count == 1)
{close Firefox}
else
{close Tab}
```

MY CODE (only the if statements don't work. Both actions are working)

```
if  (gBrowser.currentURI == "") 
    and (tabbrowser.browsers.length == 1)
then  
    goQuitApplication();
else
    gBrowser.removeTab(gBrowser.mCurrentTab);
end
```

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-currentURI) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gBrowser.currentURI` is an [`nsIURI` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURI). If you want to compare the URL to a string you should look at `gBrowser.currentURI.spec`. The URL of an "empty tab" is `about:blank` by the way. Also, I guess that you want to use JavaScript? Corrected code:

```
if (gBrowser.currentURI.spec == "about:blank" && gBrowser.browsers.length == 1)
  goQuitApplication();
else
  gBrowser.removeTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
```